# Why images inside pipline can't be loaded from views in Rails?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

I have a div which have dynamic background based on user-input, so I want to load the background directly from erb file so when I type

```
<div class="desk" style="background:url(myphoto.png);">
```

It doesn't work, although it work if I typed this line into css file
so any suggestions what's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Path is wrong it should be prefixed with "/assets/". You should use asset_path method. Without that additional problems will occur on production when md5 hash will be added at the end of filename. Try this:

```
<div class="desk" style="background:url(<%= asset_path('myphoto.png') %>);">
```

More information about that can be found in [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#coding-links-to-assets)